# jOOq :Using Spring and jOOq is there a way to hide sql statements in the stack traces

Tags: spring, jooq

I'm using jOOq with spring on a project. What I'm seeing is that SQL statements are showing up in my stack traces and ultimately my logs. I've also seen this packaged in a rest response as well. I have two questions.

1. Is this a way to configure jOOq to not print out these SQL statements in the stack trace?
2. If it possible for the bind variables to not be exposed in the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly of all, you should absolutely not expose any stack trace in your rest responses. This should be relatively simple to handle e.g. by implementing a servlet filter, or some other Spring mechanism for *all* your rest services.

Other than that, you can intercept all exceptions that pass by jOOQ by implementing an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html), particularly the [`ExecuteListener.exception()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html#exception-org.jooq.ExecuteContext-) method, where you can translate jOOQ's exceptions to whatever you want them to be.

[See also the manual's section about `ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/)

Comment: This is how to do it. I also found that there were some additional SQL statements in the throwable message so I pulled that out as well.